# For convex functions $f(x)>1,g(x)>1, x\in \mathbb{R}$, is the product $(f\cdot g)(x)$ necessarily convex?

Tags: convex-analysis

From what I understand, this is how it is:

assume $f\cdot g$ is concave.
then,
$$(f\cdot g)(0)>1$$
by this and the assumption, the product must be less than $1$ for some real $x$. thus, at least one of the functions at $x$ must be less than $1$, which brings to a contradiction.

hence, $(f\cdot g)(x)$ is convex  $\square$.

is this train of thought correct?

Comment: That a function is not concave does not imply that it is convex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, your arguments are wrong.

For a counterexample, take
$$\begin{cases}
f(x) &= 2 +(x-2)^2\\
g(x) &= 2 +(x+2)^2
\end{cases}$$

which are both convex and greater than one while $f \cdot g$ is not convex.